# How to make 1 variable minus the other variable always positive?

Tags: python

Hi so i want to make 1 variable minus the other variable then see if the number will be less then a certain number. However sometimes when one variable minus the other one, it will produce a negative number which will always be less then the number. How do i make it such that the variables minusing each other will give a positive number always

```
a = int(input("Input a integer")
b = int(input("Input a integer")
if a - b < 3 :
print(a-b is close to equaling 0)
```

Comment: you can use abs(a-b). abs() is a built-in function which gives a positive value of any number in return. It means it converts any negative number into a positive number and positive numbers remain unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

May be you are looking for something like this  -

```
a = int(input("Input a integer"))
b = int(input("Input a integer"))
if abs(a - b) < 3 :
    print("a-b is close to equaling 0")
```

`abs` function turns your result into positive. There is also indentation and syntax error in your print statement, `"` is missing. Also closing `)` is missing on line 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `abs` function. It's like `|a - b|` in math.
Or in other words, it returns the absolute value—will make the number positive.

```
if abs(a - b) < 3:
    # code
```